# A simple AMZI prolog recursion, but is not giving the correct result as expected

Tags: recursion, prolog

So this is my .pro file content (AMZI PROLOG) :

```
room(kitchen).
room(office).
room(hall).
room('dining room').
room(cellar).

door(office, hall).
door(kitchen, office).
door(hall, 'dining room').
door(kitchen, cellar).
door('dining room', kitchen).

location(desk,office).
location(apple,kitchen).
location(flashlight,desk).
location('washing machine',cellar).
location(nani,'washing machine').
location(broccoli,kitchen).
location(crackers,kitchen).
location(computer,office).
location(envelope,desk).
location(stamp,envelope).
location(key,envelope).

edible(apple).
edible(crackers).

tastes_yucky(broccoli).

here(kitchen).

is_located_in(T1,T2):-location(X,T2),is_located_in(T1,X).
```

What I want to achieve is that if I use, for example, is_located_in(X,office), then the result will be :

```
X=desk,
X=flashlight,
X=computer,
X=envelope,
X=stamp,
X=key,
no
```

(in no particular order).

That way, the result will include things that basically located in / on the object in the office, instead of things that located directly in the office.

This is the source : http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a8recurs.php

There is stated that the code are fine, but when I test it, it just returned :

```
no
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (in this order):

```
is_located_in(T1,T2):-location(T1,T2).
is_located_in(T1,T2):-location(X,T2),is_located_in(T1,X).
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems I misread a part of the website. Thanks once again.